# Best way to gain quick access to frequently used directory in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Having some problems googling this one because I'm not sure what the search term is. Shell scripting or terminal feature. What is the best way to streamline access to frequently used directories. Normally when I start a terminal it defaults to my home directory but sometimes I ike to open several terminal windows, the problem is I'm typing the cd /.../directory in each one multiple times and I need a way to not have to do this. What is the best way or just provide the search terms I could use to read about it online. Thank you

Comment: create `alias` for each directory that you very often use. Also use `cd -` to go back to last directory that you accessed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a symbolic link in your home directory:

```
$ ln -s path/to/a/really/deeply/nested/director/my-project ~/my-project

$ cd ~/my-project
```

Comment: Nice solution. Then it's good to know the difference between `cd -L ~/my-project` and `cd -P ~/my-project`.

Comment: Will this need to be saved in a `.bashrc` file, or will this symbolic link persist?

Comment: @MadmanLee - No, once a soft link is created with `ln -s`, it stays in the filesystem permanently (until deletion).
On the contrary (and perhaps this motivates your question), `alias`es are not permanent, and should be recreated each time, e.g. in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 6):

Add a variable in your .bashrc:

```
MYPROJECT=path/to/a/really/deeply/nested/director/my-project
```

to use:

```
$ cd $MYPROJECT
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also take advantage of [CDPATH](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/cdpath.shtml) variable.

And you could define a bash `function` in your `$HOME/.bashrc` like

```
 # in file ~/.bashrc
 function work() {
    cd $HOME/path/to/a/really/deeply/nested/director/my-project
 }
```

And recent bash or even better [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) may permit you things like

```
 cd **/my-project
```

Assuming you have only one deeply nested `my-project/` directory in all your tree hierarchy. The `**` is doing the equivalent of a `find` so can be slow.

Answer (score 4):

Set the CDPATH variable: it contains additional directories to be searched when you run `cd`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump).

It is like `cd` command but with the ability to learn. It maintains a database of directories you visit and assign weight to each entry.

Later you can use `j foo` to jump to a directory that contains `foo` in its name. If more than few directories have foo, it will show you a list of matches from where you can select your desired directory.

Comment: Autojump works great. I hope people read this answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias in your .bashrc

```
alias myproject="cd path/to/a/really/deeply/nested/director/my-project"
```

to use:

```
$ myproject
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bookmarks for the shell, e.g.
[bookmarks.sh](http://lug.fh-swf.de/shell/#bookmarks).

Answer (score 1):

The author of [CDPATH](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/cdpath.shtml) recommends to export CDPATH to the environment. Please keep in mind that there is a strong chance that this will subtly break shell scripts that expect directories to be in one specific place. A remedy is to put CDPATH into ~/.bashrc and not export it. Your ~/.bashrc would look like this:

```
CDPATH=/var/:/etc/
```

Note that sourced shell scripts will still pick up CDPATH in this case. [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) is certainly a much safer alternative and more convenient to use than CDPATH.

Answer (score 0):

anc is designed exactly for this use case.

https://github.com/tobimensch/anc

Here's an excerpt from the README.md:

```
# make the current directory the default anchor:
$ anc s

# go to /etc, then /, then /usr/local and then back to the default anchor:
$ cd /etc; cd ..; cd usr/local; anc

# go back to /usr/local :
$ anc b

# add another anchor:
$ anc a $HOME/test

# view the list of anchors (the default one has the asterisk):
$ anc l
(0) /path/to/first/anchor *
(1) /home/usr/test

# jump to the anchor we just added:
# by using its anchor number
$ anc 1
# or by jumping to the last anchor in the list
$ anc -1

# add multiple anchors:
$ anc a $HOME/projects/first $HOME/projects/second $HOME/documents/first

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/projects/first
$ anc pro fir

# use text matching to jump to $HOME/documents/first
$ anc doc fir

# add anchor and jump to it using an absolute path
$ anc /etc
# is the same as
$ anc a /etc; anc -1

# add anchor and jump to it using a relative path
$ anc ./X11 #note that "./" is required for relative paths
# is the same as
$ anc a X11; anc -1

# using wildcards you can add many anchors at once
$ anc a $HOME/projects/*

# use shell completion to see a list of matching anchors
# and select the one you want to jump to directly
$ anc pro[TAB]
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of anc.

Answer (score -1):

I've written a script for that. Here's the link to it: https://github.com/aderchox/pev

All instructions are on the GitHub page already, but a brief description of it is also as follows.

Add a directory to your list like this:

```
pev add myDir /path/to/my/dir
```

Now typing:

```
pev show
```

will show:

```
   |   NAMES               VALUES
   |   ----------          ----------
   |   pev_myDir           "/path/to/my/dir"
```

Now to *cd* to the *myDir* directory, you can easily type this from anywhere:

```
cd $pev_myDir
```

You will also be able to do any other thing like this too:

```
# copy "file" from another path to the "myDir" directory
cp /path/to/file $pev_myDir
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: -1. Feedback: Not quoting variables is usually OK in zsh. The question is tagged `bash`, your code uses Bash-specific syntax, the documentation mentions `.bashrc`. In Bash [you should double-quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/108618) or else [bad things will happen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/108618). This is enough for me to consider your code (and answer) flawed. The downvote is not to punish you for your willingness to help; it's only to warn other users. If you debug the code then I will revoke my vote. (Leave me a comment starting with @Kamil to get my attention).